# Uploading an image from iOS to Azure File Share

Tags: ios, azure

I have found documentation for uploading an image from iOS to a blob container in Azure - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage
using the https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-ios library

But I wish to upload directly to a file share. Is there a way to do this?
It needs to be implemented using SAS authentication.

Comment: Do you **have** to use the library you mentioned in your question?

Comment: No. It seems this library only allows me to upload directly to a container so it doesn't work for my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I am not familiar with iOS programming thus I will not be able to provide you any code. However you can use the steps below to write code.

Assuming you have a SAS URL for the file share in which you wish to upload the file, you can simply use Azure Storage REST API to upload the file in a file share. You should be able to use built-in HTTP functionality in the programming language of your choice to do that.

Let's assume that you have a SAS URL for the file share in the following format: `https://<account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<share-name>?<sas-token>`.

First thing you would need to do is insert the file name that you wish to upload in this SAS URL so that you get a SAS URL for the file. Your SAS URL would look something like: `https://<account-name>.file.core.windows.net/<share-name>/<file-name>?<sas-token>`.

Next you would need to create an empty file. You will use [`Create File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-file) REST API operation. Do not worry about the `Authorization` request header there as it is already included in the SAS. Only request header you would need to include is `x-ms-content-length` value of which should be the size of the file you want to upload. This will create an empty file having size as that of the file you want to upload.

Once this operation completes, next you would need to upload the data in the empty file you just created. You will use [`Put Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-range) operation. The request headers you need to include are `x-ms-range` (value of which should be `bytes=0-file-length - 1`) and `Content-Length` (value of which should be the length of your file). The request body will contain the file contents.

Using these steps you should be able to upload a file in a file share.